# Return statement in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

How is if else working fine in this code snippet without any syntactical errors.

```
def even_or_odd(number):
    return 'Odd' if number % 2 else 'Even'
```

In Python3 if and else introduce code blocks and should be terminated by ":" (a colon), but in the code snippet above inside return statements there is no ":" after if and else.Why is python not showing syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if` and `else` only require colons when used in *statements*. But here they are used in an *expression*. No colons are allowed in the expression. The [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) has the rule:

```
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
```

No need to be surprised here, it is very common for languages to use the same words or symbols for completely different things in different contexts. For example, in Python, the `*` is used both for multiplication and for packing and unpacking list elements.